# Why isn't this loop outputting the modified CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, for-loop

Instead of manually writing six instances of ":nth-child()," I would like to use a for loop to write this CSS for each instance.

I've put line three of the code into the console and ran it manually entering in numbers instead of the variable, and it works as desired. I am attempting to use -ms-grid-column for IE11 compatibility.

```
function gridLayout () {
  for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    $('.grid-container .grid-item:nth-child(' + i + ')').css({'-ms-grid-column': "'" + i + "'"})
    }
  }
```

When running console.log, I can confirm the loop is iterating correctly, it just doesn't seem to change the actual CSS.

Comment: Look into string templates, e.g. `.grid-item:nth-child${i}`

Comment: `'-ms-grid- column'` -> `'-ms-grid-column'`?

Comment: Why the magic number `6`? `$(".grid-container .grid-item").css("-ms-grid-column", (idx) => (idx + 1))`

Comment: @Andreas, I only have six instances of that element on the page I'll be using. Thank you for your feedback on this. I'll take a look at your suggestion.

Comment: In the future, consider building a [runnable snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 2):

The way you are doing it is wrong. The value you are setting would be `'1'` not the string of `1`.

```
$('.grid-container .grid-item:nth-child(' + i + ')')
  .css({
    '-ms-grid-column': i
  })
```

Comment: Funny, you mention that. I actually implemented that way originally, but it wasn't passing without the quotes. I'll go back and take a look at that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
function gridLayout() {
  for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    $(".grid-item:nth-child(" + i + ")").css("-ms-grid-column", i);
  }
}
```

there are two little problems:

1-`-ms-grid- column` would be replaced with `-ms-grid-column`
just a syntax error.

2- you should pass `i` by value not as string.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but code-only answers are not very useful.  Explain what you've done and why, or add some comments to your code, or both.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an extra `}` bracket. Not sure about the support for the `-ms-grid-column` property.

```js
function gridLayout () {
  for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    $('.grid-container .grid-item:nth-child('+i+')').css({'background': '#' +i+i+i });
  }
}
gridLayout();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="grid-container">
  <li class="grid-item">Item</li>
  <li class="grid-item">Item</li>
  <li class="grid-item">Item</li>
  <li class="grid-item">Item</li>
  <li class="grid-item">Item</li>
  <li class="grid-item">Item</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: That's why I should stop using my phone's keyboard 